# Changing click code to a auto loopable version

Tags: jquery, slideshow

i have this bit of code:

```
function slideshow_animateClick(){
    slideshowItem_position = 0 - (slideshowItem_place * 1920);
    $('#slideshowContent').stop().animate({'left':slideshowItem_position + 'px'}, 1000, 'swing');
  }
```

... which is a left/right buttons click function in a horizontal slideshow.

I need to copy this to a loopable version. Basically I want the slideshow to play by itself until the left/right buttons are clicked. Once that happens, it would be nice to set some sort of idle time condition after wich the slideshow would resume the autoplay again.

Full context - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W3Dub/)

Thanx.

Pedro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Added fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jnS3H/12/ with your code and a fix.

To do an interval timer, you can do something like this:

```
//create a function to handle the auto rotate
function autoRotate() {
    //code here for what happens every n seconds
}

//create a function that holds the interval to do an auto rotate push
function rotate(){
    var startRotate = setInterval(function(){  //Start the autorotate on load to rotate every 2 seconds.      
        autoRotate();
    }, 2000);
}

$('.rightarrow, .leftarrow').click(function(){
    clearInterval(startRotate);  //Stops the auto-animation
    clearTimeout(startAgain);   //Stops the starting again - incase you click again, it resets the timeout
    //write some code here to do something when you click on the right arrow
    var startAgain = setTimeout(function(){  //Then create a timeout to start rotating again after you click
        rotate();
    }, 2000);
});

$(document).load(function(){
    rotate();
});
```

This is very loose code of course, you will have to fill in the blanks and test it, but I believe the principal is correct.

Comment: Thanx for the feedback. I've adapted the code and it autoplays now - there's just one problem: it doesn't stop at click - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jnS3H/).

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/jnS3H/12/  Took me a while to figure out what was happening, but I forgot to add the global variables to start, so they can be cleared in any other function.  I then created a function to only run once (on click).  What was happening before was it was clearing the timeout, then setting it again, but it would never clear it again because every instance of .on was making a new timout.

Comment: You got it! I'm glad I could help